# Order by on mutable columns in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a table with schema below :

```
create table xx(
 bucket_id int,
 like_count int,
 photo_id int,
 username text,
 PRIMARY KEY(bucket_id,like_count,photo_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (like_count DESC)
```

Here i can fetch all records in in descending order of like_count. But i need to update like_count at some point in my app, which i am not able to do because its part of primary key.

If i remove it from primary key,  i can not get sorted results based on like_count. What would be correct way to tackle this problem in cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Cassandra is not a good fit for dealing with mutable orders. (Consider Redis Sorted Sets instead)
With that said, you can actually achieve this using CAS-like semantics (compare-and-set) and light-weight transactions which will make your update around 20x slower.

You will also need an additional table that will serve as a lookup for current like_count per bucket_id/photo_id.

```
create table yy (
  bucket_id int,
  photo_id int,
  like_count int,
  PRIMARY KEY((bucket_id,photo_id))
)
```

Then do a light-weight-transactional delete from xx followed (if success) by an re-insert into xx and update to yy:
Some pseudo code:

```
//CAS loop (supposedly in a function of args: bucket_id, photo_id, username, new_score)
for (;;) {

  //read current score (the assumption here is that the bucket_id/photo_id entry already exists in both xx and yy)
  ResultSet rs1 = select like_count from yy where bucket_id = ? and photo_id = ?
  int old_score = rs1.one().getInt(0)

  //same score don't do anything
  if (new_score == old_score) break;

  //attempt to delete using light-weight transaction (note usage of IF EXISTS)
  ResultSet r2 = delete from xx where bucket_id = ? and photo_id = ? and like_count = old_score IF EXISTS
  if (rs2.one().getBool(0)) {

    //if delete was successful, reinsert with the new score
    insert bucket_id, photo_id, photo_id, username, like_count into xx values (?, ?, ?, new_score)

    //update lookup table
    update yy set like_count = new_score where bucket_id = ? and photo_id = ?

    //we are done!
    break;
  }

  //delete was not successful, someone already updated the score
  //try again in a next CAS iteration
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `like_count` from `PRIMARY KEY` definition and perform sorting on the application. If this change happens very rarely on few keys you can think to remove the whole entry and rewrite it with updated value but I don't recommend this solution.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: The table has like 10-15k records and it has to support paging too. With your solution the application has to sort all records for each page.

Comment: sorry for down-voting this without a comment, but i think you answer does not give a general solution.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - imho a downvote should be reserved for misleading/wrong answers but this is not the case. If you don't think it provide a general solution simply don't up-vote